# Is it secure to pass static value for CryptoJS AES encryption key?

Tags: encryption, base64, aes, cryptojs

I want to encrypt all my form data with crypto js AES encryption. Is it good to keep the encrypt key value in client side like below.Kindly suggest.

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("234234234DFDFDF343434DFDFDF")
      , iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("234234324234324")
      , data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(str)
      , encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
```

Comment: Assuming you want to encrypt posted data from client to server. The best and most secure option you have is using TLS (https).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is generally not secure.

First of all, you wrongly state your goal. AES encryption is not a goal, it is a means to an end. What you want to do is to keep your form data confidential. The form data is called "the message" in crypto terminology.

If you need to send your message to a server, and then let the server have the decrypted form, then you need *transport security*. It's best to use TLS for that. Commonly JavaScript doesn't have any means to create a trust relationship with the server (your browser uses it's certificate store with trusted certificates for that). So in that case you cannot rely on JavaScript security.

Sometimes you want to keep your front end from decrypting the messages. In that case you could send a *public key* such as an RSA public key over the secure channel. Then you could encrypt the form data using RSA and AES (hybrid cryptography). Your backend would then be able to decrypt the messages. This scheme still fails if your front end sends the wrong key though, as the message would be encrypted with a public key from another party. So this assumes that the front end software cannot be easily hacked (or replaced altogether by a different server, subverting the traffic).

Even if you could use a trusted AES key then using CBC for transport mode security will definitely enable plaintext or padding oracle attacks. You're lacking *way* too much experience with crypto to pull this off. Use TLS, that's hard enough (to secure, using it is relatively easy).